# Select all text with similar formatting in Word 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, formatting

I'm using Word 2011 for Mac.

I'm writing my thesis and I now need to format them. I initially wrote some using Google Docs, and when I downloaded and try to format using word, I found that I need to restructure these text because the formatting is gone.

One way is to find the words with similar formatting, I found this [answer online](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/how-to-select-text-with-similar-format/5d2c6a3f-e265-4856-b296-000188c146ca), and many similar ones. However, the problem with the Word 2011 for Mac is that, under the "Home" tab, on the right most side, there's no "Select" button. Therefore I got no clue on how to find text with similar formatting.

Help appreciated.

PS: Please don't recommend me to use Latex..

Comment: As far as I know, the technique used by the article you reference relies on paragraph and character styles to find "similar" text. If that is what you want, the "Select", or rather "Select All" button is in the Styles toolbox, near the top right. Otherwise, I think you will need to work out what formatting you need to find (bold, 15pt, whatever) and use Edit->FInd->Advanced Find and Replace.... In there, click the down arrow near the bottom on the left and you will see buttons that let you specify the formatting you want to find.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no such command on the Mac version.  You can select all text of a certain style, which might work.  The button, however, is painful to find, and I'm answering this partly so I can find it when I forget in 6 months.

Open the 'Styles' panel like so:

View > Toolbox  /  Styles 
(Styles is a subheading under Toolbox on the View Menu.)

Then put the cursor on the bit of text you want and click "Select All" in the top right of that Styles panel.  This only selects all the text which has that style as its base, however, which may not do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what was required for me. I got some a large chunk of some 20 - 30 pages copied from Chrome into Word but there were some cases the formatting ( line gaps ) above and below some headers were too much that I wanted to reduce. I selected it by the tip shown above, then went to formatting buttons and changed the Spacing before and after. Very useful feature but as mentioned a bit difficult to find, I almost gave up finding this option and was thinking to fix it manually :D